# How do I take a screenshot of a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to get screenshots of my web app. But I'm not able to use images from URLs due to CORS restrictions even after using proxy. Any alternatives available for html2canvas?

(I need to take the screenshot from within the html page - on the click of a button)

Comment: Can you add your code sample here

Comment: this is not what SO is there for. please have a google or two to see what possibilities there are. also, this question has been answered many times ago. please post questions that are code specific

Answer (score 1):

you can use `cutycapt` for taking screenshot of webpages , please see this link for full documentation http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I need to take the screenshot from within the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas should work, atleast it works fine for me

try

```
html2canvas($('#map'), {
                    useCORS: true,
                    allowTaint:true,
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                       document.body.appendChild( canvas );
                    }
});
```

Focus on that `useCORS` and `allowTaint:true`